# ¿Cómo mostrar imágenes con PHP y MySql mostrado con una hoja de estilo?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, css3

Lo que quiero es que me muestre la imagen con unos `div` pero no logro que se me salga en fila de 3, sino que me lo muestra en una sola columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale de esa manera y la quiero de esta forma...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código *HTML*:

```
<!--div class="wrapper margin-bot">
    <article class="col-1">
        <div class="prev-indent-bot">
            <figure class="img-border"><a href="#"><img src="images/page1-img13.jpg" alt="" /></a></figure>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <h6>Luz frontal izquierda</h6>
        <h6>$25.00</h6>
        <p class="p2">Luz para hondas frontal izquierda, se encuentra nueva en empaque, con optimas condiciones venta por...</p>
        <a class="button" href="descripcion.html">Leer Mas</a>
    </article>
    <article class="col-1">
        <div class="prev-indent-bot">
            <figure class="img-border"><a href="#"><img src="images/page1-img11.jpg" alt="" /></a></figure>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <h6>Radiador</h6>
        <h6>$47.00</h6>
        <p class="p2">Venta de radiador usado, se encuentra en buenas condiciones y optimo para su manipulacion.</p>
        <a class="button" href="descripcion.html">Leer Mas</a>
    </article>
    <article class="col-2">
        <div class="prev-indent-bot">
            <figure class="img-border"><a href="#"><img src="images/page2-img2.png" alt="" /></a></figure>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <h6>Llantas</h6>
        <h6>$45.00 a $70.00</h6>
        <p class="p2">Venta de llantas al mayoreo y minoreo, de todo tamaño, nueva y usada a disposicion.</p>
        <a class="button" href="descripcion.html">Leer Mas</a>
    </article>
</div-->

<!--div class="wrapper">
    <article class="col-1">
        <div class="prev-indent-bot">
            <figure class="img-border"><a href="#"><img src="images/page2-img1.png" alt="" /></a></figure>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <h6>Accesorios</h6>
        <h6>Precios Variados</h6>
        <p class="p2">Venta de gran cantidad de accesorios para todo tipo de vehiculo, tanto usados como nuevos.</p>
        <a class="button" href="descripcion.html">Leer Mas</a>
    </article>
    <article class="col-1">
        <div class="prev-indent-bot">
            <figure class="img-border"><a href="#"><img src="images/amortiguador.jpg" alt="" /></a></figure>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <h6>Amortiguador</h6>
        <h6>$42.00</h6>
        <p class="p2">Venta de un amortiguador nuevo, en buen estado y con su presentacion de originalidad..</p>
        <a class="button" href="descripcion.html">Leer Mas</a>
    </article>
    <article class="col-2">
        <div class="prev-indent-bot">
            <figure class="img-border"><a href="#"><img src="images/velocidades.jpg" alt="" /></a></figure>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <h6>Caja de velocidades</h6>
        <h6>$250.00</h6>
        <p class="p2">En venta caja de velocidades usada, se encuentra en buenas condiciones para su uso, 1 año de uso con..</p>
        <a class="button" href="descripcion.html">Leer Mas</a>
    </article>
</div-->
```

Código *PHP*:

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="wrapper margin-bot">';
    echo '<figure class="img-border"><a href="descripcion.html">';
    echo'<article class="col-1">';
    echo'<div class="prev-indent-bot">';
    echo'<article class="col-1">';
    $sql=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repuesto");

    while($res=  mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo'<div class="prev-indent-bot">';
        echo'<figure class="img-border"><a href="descripcion.html">';
        echo '<img src="../Administrador/pages/RepuestoCRUD/'.$res["imagen_repuesto"].'"width="230" heigth="220">';
        echo'<img src="" alt="" /></a></figure>';
        echo'<div class="clear"></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo'<h6>'.$res["nombre_repuesto"].'</h6>';
        echo'<h6>'.$res["precio_repuesto"].'</h6>';
        echo'<p class="p2">'.$res["descripcion_repuesto"].'</p>';
        echo'<a class="button" href="descripcion.html">Leer Mas</a>';
        echo'</article>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: podrías añadir el código html?

Comment: con gusto un momento @ReneLimon

Comment: @AlexanderArias :) Asegúrate de agregar el código que has trabajado cuando preguntes en StackOverflow :) Un pequeño consejo para evitar esas personas tipo ... "DOWNVOTE, DOWNVOTE EVERYWHERE".

Comment: soy nuevo aca casi no se nada de StackOverflow

Comment: @AlexanderArias No te preocupes :) Sólo es un consejo

Comment: @AlexanderArias Te he dejado un ejemplo, donde puedes ver la modificacion de tus sentencias, ya que `mysql` esta absuelto y debes utilizar `mysqli` para ello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo completo como podria quedar.

En primer lugar estas utilizando `mysql` que ha quedado absuelto y para ello debería utilizar `mysqli`, o personalmente te aconsejo sentencias preparadas.

> Manual sentencia **prepare()**:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

**Ejemplo:**

Hoja de estilos CSS:

```
/* Eliminamos flujo flotante (CSS3). */
.holder-clear {         
    height:   1%; 
    width: 100%;  
    overflow: hidden;    
}

/* Reglas estandares para nuestras cajas flotantes. */
.col2, .col3, .col4 { 
    float:left;
    width: 100%;    
}

/* 2 cajas flotantes */
.col2 { max-width: 50%; }

/* 3 cajas flotantes */
.col3 { max-width: 33.3%; } 

 /* 4 cajas flotantes */
.col4 { max-width: 25%; }

.padding { padding: 1rem; }
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
    //Conexión MySQL
    require_once'tu_conexion.php';

    //Sentencia
    $sql=  mysqli_query($tu_conexion, "SELECT * FROM repuesto");
    //Si existe registros en la Base de datos.
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {

        //Caja, para añadir cajas flotantes (No puede ir dentro de while, si no en cada registro te elimina el flujo flotante de tus caja).
        echo "<div class=holder-clear>";

        while($res= mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

            //Es importante añadir la caja flotante en tu bucle while.
            echo "          
                <div class='col3 padding'>

                    <img src=turuta/".$res['imagen_repuesto']." alt='imagen (.jpg)' />

                    <h2>".$res['nombre_repuesto']."</h2>

                    <p>".$res['precio_repuesto']."</p>

                    <div>
                        ".$res['descripcion_repuesto']."
                    </div>

                    <a class=button href=descripcion.html>Leer más</a>
                </div>

            ";

        } 

        echo "</div>";//Fin eliminación cajas flotantes.

    } else { //Caso falso.
        echo "0 registros encontrados";
    }
    //Cerramos conexión despues de no utilizarlo.
    mysqli_close($tu_conexion);

?>
```

Comment: me ayudarías a entender tu código, quiero hacer lo mismo pero no me queda, soy novato pero quiero aprender. Saludos.

Comment: @LuisChimal que parte del codigo no entiendes `PHP` o `CSS`?

Answer (score 1):

Esto es cosa de Css. Podría quedar así:

```
while($res=  mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   echo '<div class="col">';
   //Todo el dom de las imgs 
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Donde css:

```
.col{
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  width:33%;
}
```

El width 33% porque tomará una tercera parte de la pantalla, sea cual sea su resolución, y así puedes tener 3 columnas.

Esto puede solucionar el problema que planteas en tu pregunta.

**Nota:** El problema nuevo que te enfrentarás es que debes hacerlo responsivo para smarthphones y tablets. Te recomiendo mucho que mejor uses [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) , es muy sencillo de usar.

Answer (score 1):

de una manera sencilla:

```
article
{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto agregando este css:

CSS:

```
.col{
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  width:25%;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'clases/conexion.php';
?>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleimag.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>  
<?php                                           

$sql=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repuesto");    

while($res=  mysql_fetch_array($sql)){    

    echo '<div class="col">';    
    echo '<img src="../Administrador/pages/RepuestoCRUD/'.$res["imagen_repuesto"].'"width="230" heigth="220">';
    echo'<h6>'.$res["nombre_repuesto"].'</h6>';
    echo'<h6>'.$res["precio_repuesto"].'</h6>';
    echo'<p class="p2">'.$res["descripcion_repuesto"].'</p>';
    echo'<a class="button" href="descripcion.html">Leer Mas</a>';

    //Todo el dom de las imgs
    echo '</div>';
}                                                   
?>    
</body>
</html>
```